# Android: Add fragments by looking up container with tag instead of ID

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating multiple instances of a fragment with a for loop. Within each fragment, I need to add another set of child fragments. In doing that, I need to find the correct container. If I use the ID of the container, all the child fragments gets added to the first parent fragment, instead of their own parent fragments.

In my main fragment:

```
for (....) {
    ParentFragment parentFragment = new ParentFragment();
    parentFragment.setSomeData(data);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, parentFragment, data);
}

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now I have N Parent Fragments.

Within each ParentFragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ChildFragment childFragment = new ChildFragment();
    childFragment.setSomeData(data);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.parent_fragment_container, childFragment).commit();
}
```

The issue is, all instances of `ChildFragment` gets added to the first ParentFragment because "R.id.parent_fragment_container" is a constant for all ParentFragment. It doesn't change for each instance of ParentFragment.

Because I have unique tag for each instance of ParentFragment, can I lookup the container using this tag instead of `R.id.parent_fragment_container`?

XML definitions:

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_parent.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `Fragment` inside another `Fragment` should be handled by that parent `Fragment`s child `FragmentManager`, obtained with `getChildFragmentManager()`. You won't have your current issue if it's done like that.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Can you leave that as an answer? I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragment`s inside another `Fragment` should be handled with that parent `Fragment`'s `FragmentManager` – obtained with `getChildFragmentManager()` – rather than the `Activity`'s `FragmentManager`.

The child `FragmentManager` will search only the parent `Fragment`'s `View` for the given container ID, so you won't end up with all of the child `Fragment`s in the first found container, as was happening when the `Activity`'s `FragmentManager` just used the first `parent_fragment_container` it would find in the `Activity`'s overall hierarchy.